# RSocket tests fail when run together - but pass individually

Tags: java, spring, junit, rsocket, rsocket-java

I have multiple tests that test different routes and in separate classes that require the setup of an RSocket client and then to dispose the client here's an example below.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class RSocketClientToServerITest {

private static RSocketRequester requester;

 @BeforeAll
    public static void setupOnce(@Autowired RSocketRequester.Builder builder, @Value("${spring.rsocket.server.port}") Integer port) {
        requester = builder
                .connectTcp("localhost", port)
                .block();
    }

 @Test
     public void testRequestGetsResponse() {
         // Send a request message (1)
          Mono<Message> result = requester
                 .route("request-response")
                 .data(new Message("TEST", "Request"))
                 .retrieveMono(Message.class);
 
        // Verify that the response message contains the expected data (2)
        StepVerifier
                  .create(result)
                  .consumeNextWith(message -> { 
assertThat(message.getOrigin()).isEqualTo(RSocketController.SERVER); assertThat(message.getInteraction()).isEqualTo(RSocketController.RESPONSE);
assertThat(message.getIndex()).isEqualTo(0);})
                 .verifyComplete();
     }  

     @AfterAll
      public static void tearDownOnce() {
          requester.rsocket().dispose();
      }
}
```

However the issue is, they all use the same RSocket Port and they all dispose of the RSocket client once the test is complete, and that impacts other tests. How can I avoid that?

Thanks!